# An hypothesis for self-dual convolutional codes

Tags: coding-theory

After trying to characterize self-dual convolutional codes of rate $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{2}{4}$ I stumbled upon the following observation:

I was explicitely looking at the necessary condition
$$(0)=G(z)*H(z)^T\stackrel{(1)}{=}G(z)*G(z)^T=(g_1(z),g_2(z)) 
\begin{pmatrix}
g_1(z) \\
g_2(z)
\end{pmatrix}=g_1^2(z)+g_2^2(z),$$

where $(1)$ follows from the code being self-dual. There are non-constant polynomial solutions here (for $p\equiv 1 \ mod \ 4$), but in this case I always seem to find an element in $ker(H(z))=ker(G(z))$, which is not in $span(G(z))$. And this is a contradiction. This made me think of the hypothesis that

any generator matrix of a self-dual convolutional code must have all its entries in $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Is this statement true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $q\equiv1\pmod4$ there is, indeed, an element $i\in\Bbb{F}_q$ such that $i^2+1=0$.

This means that
$$0=g_1(z)^2+g_2(z)^2=g_1(z)^2-(ig_2(z))^2=(g_1(z)-ig_2(z))(g_1(z)+ig_2(z)).$$

The polynomial ring $\Bbb{F}_q[z]$ is an integral domain, so this implies that either
$g_1(z)+ig_2(z)=0$ or $g_1(z)-ig_2(z)=0$. In either case we have
$$
\gcd(g_1(z),g_2(z))=g_1(z).
$$
But, it is usually required that the generator matrix of a convolutional code is *canonical* (the term used by at least McEliece's chapter in the Handbook). One of the properties of a canonical generator matrix is that its maximal size minors, here $g_1(z)$ and $g_2(z)$, must have $\gcd=1$. McEliece uses the term *basic* for this, don't know about your textbook. Anyway, unless you have this property your generator matrix will be *catastrophic*, and that is excluded by every telecommunication engineer and researcher.

So the conditions $g_1(z)^2+g_2(z)^2=0$ and $G(z)=(g_1(z),g_2(z))$ canonical together imply, as you suspected, that $g_1(z)$ and $g_2(z)$ must both be constants from $\Bbb{F}_q$.

---

Whenever I teach a course on convolutional codes, I **never** consider alphabet fields other than $\Bbb{F}_2$ :-) There the condition $g_1(D)^2+g_2(D)^2=0$ is rather pointless because Freshman's Dream tells us that this happens iff $g_1(D)=g_2(D)$. The dual of a binary $(2,1)$ convolutional code is, in a sense, always *equivalent* to the original code simply becase if $G(D)=(g_1(D),g_2(D))$ is the generator matrix of a code $\mathcal{C}$, then $(g_2(D),g_1(D))$ is the generator matrix of $\mathcal{C}^\perp$ by virtue of $2g_1(D)g_2(D)=0$.

---

In the case of $(4,2)$ codes the game is probably more interesting. Too late an hour for me to delve there now.

Comment: On second thought, the existence of $i$ is immaterial. From $g_1(z)^2+g_2(z)^2=0$ we can already deduce that every irreducible monic factor of $g_1(z)$ is also a factor of $g_2(z)$ and vice versa. The rest of the argument goes through.